# how to implement request timeout in android?

Tags: android

friends,

I'm running into an issue when i try to call webservice and the server/internet is not available. It appears that the
connection is taking a long time to timeout

can i set timout manually to show error messgage to user?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your HttpClient this way.

```
    BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, connectionTimeoutInMs);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it did not throw an exception, furthermore, the status parsed with a 200 OK.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to do it this way:

```
URL url;
URLConnection connection;
try {
    url = new URL("http://foo.bar.com");
    connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(3000); // set 3 seconds for timeout
    connection.connect();
}catch(SocketTimeoutException ss){
    // show message to the user
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of timeout:

1. Connection Timeout

that is the time until a connection is established

2. Socket Timeout

that is the timeout for waiting for data to be received, setting any of them to 0 means infinite timeout, and it's the default value of both, setting one of them doesn't affect the other.

```
    try{

    BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    //this will set socket timeout
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, /*say*/ 3000);

    //this will set connection timeout
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3000);

    client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    String url = "some-url";            
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    //here use the received response

    }
    catch(ConnectTimeoutException ex)    {
       //handle connection timeout here
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException ex)   {
       //handle socket timeout here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work always...


try     {   
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, Constants.CONN_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, Constants.SOCKET_CONN_TIMEOUT);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    url = "write-your-web-url-here";            
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity`enter code here`();
    if(entity != null) is = entity.getContent();
}catch(ConnectTimeoutException timeoutException)    {
    System.out.println("ConnectTimeoutException Occured...");
}catch(SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException)   {
    System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException Occured...")
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception Occured...");
}
```